# How to change ViewController with mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

So I'm in the process of learning Xamarin with MVVMCross and I want to change views. I can do it in my ViewModel by doing the following:

```
ShowViewModel<ProfileViewModel>();
```

But then it comes up as a Navigation with a back button I want to to move from one view to another view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button is part of the UiNavigationController - it's the default way that view controllers are presented.

As you progress further through learning about UiKit and about MvvmCross you will discover plenty of ways to change this behaviour (search for custom MvvmCross presenters if you want to learn more now) but an easy first step might be to set HidesBackButton in your second ViewController - see Wally's article in http://morewally.com/cs/blogs/wallym/archive/2012/05/29/hiding-the-back-button-in-a-navigation-controller-with-monotouch.aspx

this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true, true)